# Query Optimization - <Derived 2> Type: ALL, Key = NULL

Tags: mysql, optimization, derived, explain

Similar questions have been asked, and I've reworked this query with every suggestion, but can't figure out the issue. When submit the following query to EXPLAIN EXTENDED I receive both 'Type' = 'ref' and a key was found for each table (although I don't know why 'isActive' is the key chosen for the derived table 'CS.'

```
SELECT 
    distinct
    CS.BLNUMBER
    ,CS.CONTAINER
    ,s.status
    #,s.location
    #,s.dateandtime 
FROM 
    CUSTOMERSHIPMENTS CS
INNER JOIN SHIPMENTS S 
    ON CS.BLNUMBER = S.BLNUMBER 
    AND CS.CONTAINER = S.CONTAINERNUMBER
WHERE
    cs.blnumber <>''
    and CS.CDATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
    and CS.ISACTIVE = 1
    and cs.hostcompany_id = cs.company_id
    AND S.STATUS <> ''
```

When I assign this join an alias and join again the 'customershipments' table, this time called 'CS2' as in:

```
FROM
(
SELECT 
    distinct
    CS.BLNUMBER
    ,CS.CONTAINER
    ,s.status
    #,s.location
    #,s.dateandtime 
FROM 
    CUSTOMERSHIPMENTS CS
INNER JOIN SHIPMENTS S 
    ON CS.BLNUMBER = S.BLNUMBER 
    AND CS.CONTAINER = S.CONTAINERNUMBER
WHERE
    cs.blnumber <>''
    and CS.CDATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
    and CS.ISACTIVE = 1
    and cs.hostcompany_id = cs.company_id
    AND S.STATUS <> ''
) temp

INNER JOIN CUSTOMERSHIPMENTS CS2 
ON temp.blnumber = CS2.BLNUMBER
and temp.container = cs2.container
```

EXPLAIN EXTENDED now immediately tells me:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY derived2    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    45120   100.00  Using temporary
```

BUT "Derived2" is pointing back to EXPLAIN EXTENDED ID's 2 which is my join between CS and S. How did it go from having a key, to not finding one? I canNot figure this out.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  5.6 has some subquery improvements; 5.7 has more.

Answer (score 3):

A subquery has no indexes.  (See footnote.)  Because of that, it is advisable to plan on the subquery running first, then `JOINing` to the other table(s).  In your case, cs2 needs the composite `INDEX(BLNUMBER, container)` (in either order).

Here's how the whole query will be executed:

1. Perform the subquery, storing the results into a temporary table (Engine `MEMORY` or `MyISAM`).
2. `JOIN` to `CS2` using whatever it can of `BLNUMBER` and/or `container`.

Meanwhile, the optimal indexes for the subquery are

- `CS`: `(ISACTIVE, CDATE)`  -- more on this below
- `S`: `(BLNUMBER, CONTAINERNUMBER)`

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and all of the `EXPLAIN`.  Let me guess some more...

You say that `INDEX(isactive)` was mysteriously picked?  That would be a useful index if less than something like 20% of the table had `CS.ISACTIVE = 1`.  Is that the case?  Regardless, the composite index I suggest will be better.

Are there about 45K rows in the subquery?  That takes time to generate and use.

Footnote:  In 5.6, the optimizer discovers what the best index should be for each subquery, and adds it to the tmp table.  However this may be irrelevant if `CS2` has the index I mentioned above.  That `JOIN` could go either way, so why bother creating an index on `temp` that is no better than the one on `CS2`.

Comment: You say a subquery uses not indexes but in your footnote it says 'optimizer discovers what the best index should be for each subquery.' I do have a index(BLNumber,Container) for cs and cs2. I believe something else is afoot. When I run the query it takes about 12 minutes, but returns "Query took 0.065 sec." I don't know what to make of that! My CPU hasn't been over 50% all week on m3.xlarge amazon MYSQL RDS. Your explanation was great though, and I think it will help me with this and other queries.

Comment: Do you have the "Query cache" turned on?  (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query%';`)

Comment: 5.6 will add an index; previous versions will not.  Which version are you using?

Comment: - V5.6.23

- Query cache: I dont expect the resultant data set to 'ever' be the same.

Comment: Then I, too, am stumped by the thousand-fold speedup.